# re.sub different answer with same string split across lines

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace any string with `not ...` followed by `poor` with
`good` using `re.sub()`.

```
string1 ="""The lyrics are not that poor!  
The lyrics are poor! """

print(re.sub("(not).*(poor)" , 'good' , string1 ))
```

Output:

```
The lyrics are good!  
The lyrics are poor!
```

Same code if I run taking string in single line it gives different
answer:

```
string1 ="""The lyrics are not that poor!  The lyrics are poor! """

print(re.sub("(not).*(poor)" , 'good' , string1 ))
```

Output:

```
The lyrics are good!
```

The output should have been `The lyrics are good!  The lyrics are poor!`. 
Why is it returning just `The lyrics are good!`?

Comment: Your regex is matching the first not and the last poor. The bit that is being replaced is  `not that poor!  The lyrics are poor`. This doesn't happen with the first one because the `\n` isn't matched by the `.*`.

Comment: Try `not[^.?!]+poor` instead.

Comment: They are not the same string. One contains a newline and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

In the single line version, your regex converts the entire substring `not that poor!  The lyrics are poor` to `good`.

Regexes are *greedy*, meaning they match as much as possible.  The regex does not stop at the first occurrence of `poor` -- it keeps going to the second occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

You must do `print(re.sub("(not).*?(poor)", 'good', string1))`

More details at https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy

> Laziness Instead of Greediness
>   The quick fix to this problem is to make the plus lazy instead of greedy. Lazy quantifiers are sometimes also called “ungreedy” or “reluctant”. You can do that by putting a question mark after the plus in the regex. You can do the same with the star, the curly braces and the question mark itself. So our example becomes <.+?>. Let’s have another look inside the regex engine.
>
> Again, < matches the first < in the string. The next token is the dot, this time repeated by a lazy plus. This tells the regex engine to repeat the dot as few times as possible. The minimum is one. So the engine matches the dot with E. The requirement has been met, and the engine continues with > and M. This fails. Again, the engine will backtrack. But this time, the backtracking will force the lazy plus to expand rather than reduce its reach. So the match of .+ is expanded to EM, and the engine tries again to continue with >. Now, > is matched successfully. The last token in the regex has been matched. The engine reports that  has been successfully matched. That’s more like it.

Ful lexample

```
import re

string1 = """The lyrics are not that poor!  
The lyrics are poor! """

print(re.sub("(not).*?(poor)", 'good', string1))

string1 = """The lyrics are not that poor!  The lyrics are poor! """

print(re.sub("(not).*?(poor)", 'good', string1))
```

Outputs

```
> python test123.py
The lyrics are good!
The lyrics are poor!
The lyrics are good!  The lyrics are poor!
```

Comment: that's absolutely different case which doesn't belong to the question. The different phrases, different regex types. Not sure why you are interested in it

Comment: I'm adding it as it may be useful for the OP or future users to know. Oftentimes users here post a question, then post "but it fails against these cases, why?" - cases that were not originally part of the question. This allows the OP to clarify whether they intend to also match certain edge-cases.